# How to unmarshal JSON to multiple items with JBoss Fuse (camel)?

Tags: java, json, jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I currently have the following simplified JSON (test.json):

```
{"type":"monkey","food":"banana"},{"type":"dog","food":"bone"},{"type":"cat","food":"fish"}
```

Doing the following:

```
from("file:/tmp/input").routeId("test")
                        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                        .log("After unmarshall:\n ${body}");
```

When dropping the JSON file into the input folder, I only get the following map:

```
{type=monkey, food=banana}
```

How to get all items into the mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all then put them to an array like

```
[{"type":"monkey","food":"banana"},{"type":"dog","food":"bone"},{"type":"cat","food":"fish"}]
```

Then setup dataFormat with **useList** option true. In Xml DSL that i tried is

```
<dataFormats>
  <json id="json" library="Jackson"  useList="true"/>
</dataFormats>
```

In Java is

```
JacksonDataFormat json = new JacksonDataFormat(); 
json.useList();
```

Then use unmarshall with the preceding data format

XML DSL:

```
<unmarshal ref="json"/>
```

So you should have :

```
from("file:/tmp/input").routeId("test")
                        .unmarshal().json(json)
                        .log("After unmarshall:\n ${body}");
```

And the output is a list:

```
 [{type=monkey, food=banana}, {type=dog, food=bone}, {type=cat, food=fish}]
```

Comment: Says that json() method is not applicable for the JacksonDataFormat. And format.useList() should be json.useList() ?

Comment: Yes you are write, json is the object name, i will correct it

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you're trying to parse is not a valid JSON. If you have control of what's being sent to Camel, try wrapping it in an array, like this:

```
[{"type":"monkey","food":"banana"},{"type":"dog","food":"bone"},{"type":"cat","food":"fish"}]
```

This will net you an array of objects and should parse correctly.

If you can't control the input, you can also add the array marks as part of Camel processing, just before the `unmarshal()` call